# Проблема с доступом к api используя curl php cli

Tags: php, curl

Есть API, которое фильтрует пользователей по IP адресам. При доступе с браузера я получаю корректный ответ, введя `https://some.site/api/users`.
Когда я использую curl через `php-fpm` все работает, но когда я пытаюсь сделать это через `php-cli` ничего не работает.
Предполагаю, что проблема где-то в IP-адресе, который, возможно, не отправляется с `curl` и следовательно меня не пропускают на API. Но вот в чем именно и как это происходит (в чем главное отличие) я не пойму...

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, API_URI . $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_PWD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
```

Пробовал следующие варианты:

```php
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: 184.7.120.101", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 184.7.120.101"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:80');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '184.7.120.101');
```

Ни один не сработал.

Comment: вроде какой то пароль пропихиваете, а юзер где? но главный вопрос - что отвечает апи?

Comment: смотреть надо ответ., а также можно смотреть в https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: Вопрос на подумать на досуге: если бы подставить ip адрес было бы так просто, как вы тут довольно неуклюже пытаетесь это сделать, имело ли бы вообще смысл делать фильтрацию по IP адресам?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все оказалось проще, в `php.ini` от `php-cli` не оказалось такого расширения...и мне выдавало `false`. Сам `curl_exec` возвращает `false|SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: если не оказалось такого расширения, то никакое "false" выдавать не будет. а только ошибку.